# Deploy Spring Boot application in weblogic 11g

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic11g

Created Spring boot applciation and need to deploy in weblogic 11g. While deploying, getting some error **Error String index out of range: 29232**.

Code implements attached below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

@EnableScheduling
public class SupportServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder app) {
    return app.sources(SupportServiceApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SupportServiceApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

**Pom.xml : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.0.RELEASE
         
    
    de.basf.ap.agrilog
    support-service
    1.0.0
    support-service
    war
    Agrilog support service for self-healing Agrilog issues

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Added the **weblogic.xml and dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml** under WEB-INF folder

**weblogic.xml :**

```
<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:context-root>/support-service</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.*
        </wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.*
        </wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Answer (score 2):

So just to start off you will run into a few problems. You are using springboot 2.2.0 which will cause your dynamic web module facet to be set to 4.0. You will not be able to change this.

Next up, you are deploying to WLS11g. You not be able to deploy the .war file as WLS12c isn't even compatible with the dynamic web module of 4.0.

If you can, use a lower version of Spring Boot. 1.5.4 should work for you. Additionally if you must stay on your current version of spring boot for whatever reason see if you can deploy to another server (TomCat/Jetty)

Comment: After changing springboot version 1.5.4, I can able to deploy the applciation. But I cannot able to hit the endpoint (http://10.93.125.160:7001/test/example). Showing Error 404--Not Found .

Comment: please click the check if I have answered your question now that you can deploy.You should post another question regarding your service not working and provide code